# Cloudwatch generates a lot of costs due to large number of PutMetricData requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

cost-wise, the majority of our invoice comes from PutMetricData. I can't really see which piece sends that huge amount.
According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/logging_cw_api_calls.html, cloud trail does not trace it.
I am looking for some sort of a sum-up to find out where all that requests come from.

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks in advance

EDIT
attaching API cost spreadout
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the majority of our invoice," do you mean that CloudWatch metrics cost more than or a significant percentage of all of the other AWS services that you use?

This is extremely surprising: you can call PutMetricData 100,000 times for $1, so your usage numbers must be astronomical (calling once per second is only 86,400 per day). So surprising that I have to ask are you *sure* that it's the API calls that are running up the cost, and not the number of metrics? (and are you aware that each combination of dimensions represents a distinct metric?)

If it really is the number of PutMetricData calls, then the only way that you could accumulate those numbers is to be making a call from within a loop -- one that executes many times per second. So I would start by using your IDE (or `grep`) to find all references to the SDK function, and determining which of those is called in a loop.

There are very few reasons to call PutMetricData from within a loop, unless you expect the body of the loop to take a significant amount of time (seconds to minutes) and are using metrics to track the amount of time this takes.

Comment: Attached reports. PutMetricData is responsible for around 30% of the costs.
I breezed thru our repositories. All manual API requests are scheduled via cron with the highest possible granularity of 1 minute.
I preliminary estimated our load and it should be roughly 70 times smaller.